# When add new record in SQLite check if this name already exists in Android

Tags: android, android-sqlite, sqliteopenhelper

I have `SQLite` DB which there I am saving data and I want for each new entry to check in DB if already exists this record if yes show me a toast message if not insert the record in DB.
I want to check if the search url and native url exists or not in the DB.

Below is the code.

```
public class BookmarkDB extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public static final String DBNAME = "bookmarks.db"; // The name of the database file
    public static final int DBVERSION = 1;  // The Database version

    public static final String TBL_BOOKMARK = "bookmark";
    public static final String COL_ID = BaseColumns._ID; // equates to _id
    public static final String COl_NAME = "name";
    public static final String COl_HIDDEN = "hidden";
    public static final String COL_ICON = "icon";
    public static final String COL_NATIVEURL = "nativeurl";
    public static final String COL_SEARCHURL = "searchurl";

    SQLiteDatabase mDB;
    Context mContext;

    public BookmarkDB(Context context) {
        super(context, DBNAME, null, DBVERSION);
        mDB = this.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        // The SQL to be used to create the table
        String crt_bookmark_tbl_sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TBL_BOOKMARK + "(" +
                COL_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                COl_NAME + " TEXT, " +
                COl_HIDDEN + " INTEGER, " +
                COL_ICON + " TEXT, " +
                COL_NATIVEURL + " TEXT," +
                COL_SEARCHURL + " TEXT" +
                ")";
        db.execSQL(crt_bookmark_tbl_sql); // CREATE THE TABLE

    }


    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP IF TABLE EXISTS " + DBNAME);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public long addBookmark(long id, String name, boolean hidden, String icon, String nativeurl, String searchurl) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();


                    cv.put(COl_HIDDEN,hidden);
                    cv.put(COl_NAME,name);
                    cv.put(COL_ICON,icon);
                    cv.put(COL_NATIVEURL,nativeurl);
                    cv.put(COL_SEARCHURL,searchurl);
                  return  mDB.insert(TBL_BOOKMARK, null, cv);

        // uses the convenience insert method that builds the SQL
    }
    public ArrayList<Bookmark> getAllBookmarks() {
        ArrayList<Bookmark> rv  = new ArrayList<>();
        Cursor csr = mDB.query(TBL_BOOKMARK,null,null,null,null,null, null);

        while (csr.moveToNext()) {
            Bookmark b = new Bookmark();
            b.setId(csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(COL_ID)));
            int Icon = csr.getInt(csr.getColumnIndex(COL_ICON));
            String name = csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(COl_NAME));
            String searchUrl = csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(COL_SEARCHURL));
            b.setIcon(Icon);
            b.setName(name);
            b.setSearchUrl(searchUrl);
            b.setViewType(csr.getInt(csr.getColumnIndex(COl_NAME)));
            b.setNativeUrl(csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(COL_NATIVEURL)));
            rv.add(b);
        }
        return rv;

    }

    public void deleteBookmark(int id, String name){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        String query = "DELETE FROM " + TBL_BOOKMARK + " WHERE "
                + COL_ID + " = '" + id + "'" +
                " AND " + COl_NAME + " = '" + name + "'";

        Log.d("Deleted", "Item" + query);
        db.execSQL(query);
    }

}
```

Code for saving new record

```
public class ActivityChangeBookmark  extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ArrayList<String> listItems = new ArrayList<String>();
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    Button saveBookmark, cancelBookmark;
    TextView name, url;
    ImageView icon, mIcon;
    EditText mName, mUrl, mID;
    public static final String Save_Bookmark = "Save_Bookmark";
    static final String xmlFileName = "bookmarks.xml";
    String Url, Name;
    Integer Id;
    MyAdapter myAdapter;
     BookmarkDB bookmarkDB;
     ButtonRobotoMedium removeBookmark, sendToHomeScreen;
    ArrayList<Bookmark> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_change_bookmark);
        saveBookmark = findViewById(R.id.btnSave);
        name = findViewById(R.id.tvNameEdit);
        url = findViewById(R.id.tvURLEdit);
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.myRecyclerView);
        icon = findViewById(R.id.ivFavIcon);
        mName = findViewById(R.id.etNameEdit);
        mUrl = findViewById(R.id.etURLEdit);
        cancelBookmark = findViewById(R.id.btnCancel);
        removeBookmark = findViewById(R.id.btnRemove);
        sendToHomeScreen = findViewById(R.id.btnAddIconToDeviceScreen);
        name.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        url.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        bookmarkDB = new BookmarkDB(getApplicationContext());
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        myAdapter = new MyAdapter(getApplicationContext(), arrayList);

        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
            Url = intent.getExtras().getString("Url");
            Name = intent.getExtras().getString("Name");
            Id = intent.getExtras().getInt("ID");

            Bitmap bitmap = intent.getExtras().getParcelable("Image");
            mName.setText(Name);
            mUrl.setText(Url);
            Log.d("Id", "TakenId" + Id + Name + Url);

            icon.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            removeBookmark.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Log.d("DeletedItem", "Test" + Id + Name);
                    bookmarkDB.deleteBookmark(Id, Name);
                    myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    finish();
                }
            });
        }
         else {
            removeBookmark.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            sendToHomeScreen.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.user_bookmark);
            mName.setText("");
            mUrl.setText("");
        }



        saveBookmark.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                saveData();
                myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                finish();
                }
        });

        cancelBookmark.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                finish();
            }
        });
    }

    public void saveData() {
        Random r = new Random();
        int low = 14;
        int high = 100;
        int result = r.nextInt(high-low) + low;
        bookmarkDB.addBookmark(result, mName.getText().toString(), false, "", mUrl.getText().toString(), "http://" + mUrl.getText().toString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way would be to utilise UNIQUE thus making the column/composite columns which will result in a constraint conflict and thus not allow the row to be inserted.

What is not abundantly clear is what columns you are referring to to. The title appears to indicate that it is the **name** column, in which case you could change `COl_NAME + " TEXT, " +`, to be `COl_NAME + " TEXT UNIQUE, " +`.

The text how states *I wan't to check if the search url and native url exists or not in the DB.* This implies that it is only if a combination of both exist that you don't want to add the row, but that a combination where only one of the columns already exists should be added.

Assuming this then you could add a composite UNIQUE constraint in which case, you could add the line

```
", UNIQUE(" + COL_NATIVEURL + "," + COL_SEARCHURL + ")" +
```

This would be added after the line `COL_SEARCHURL + " TEXT" +`

If wanted the row to not be added if either existed then you could add UNIQUE to the column definitions by using :-

```
            COL_NATIVEURL + " TEXT UNIQUE," +
            COL_SEARCHURL + " TEXT UNIQUE" +
```

- Note that addBookMark would return -1 if the row wasn't added.

If the above does not suit and you want to check a column then you could base that check upon something like the following method in the BookmarkDB class:-

```
public boolean ifNativeUrlExists(String nativeUrl) {

    boolean rv = false;
    String whereclause = COL_NATIVEURL + "=?";
    String[] whereargs = new String[]{nativeUrl};
    Cursor csr = mDB.query(TBL_BOOKMARK,null,whereclause,whereargs,null,null, null)
    if (csr.getCount() > 0) {
        rv = true;
    }
    csr.close();
    return rv;
}
```

You could utilise this using something like :-

```
public void saveData() {
    Random r = new Random();
    int low = 14;
    int high = 100;
    int result = r.nextInt(high-low) + low;
    if (!bookmarkDB.ifNativeUrlExists(mUrl.getText().toString())) {
        bookmarkDB.addBookmark(result, mName.getText().toString(), false, "", mUrl.getText().toString(), "http://" + mUrl.getText().toString());
    } else {
         ..... code to indicate not added
    }
}
```

- Obviously this could be adapted quite easily for other columns.

#### Note the above is in-principle code and has not been tested or run and mat therefore contain some errors.

Comment: Where should I add the `ifNativeUrlExists()` and how ?
And to show a message if exists tell this url exists if  not then url is added.
I have tried something like this but show me `Cannot resolve method 'put(boolean, java.lang.String`
`cv.put(ifNativeUrlExists(COL_SEARCHURL), searchurl);`

Comment: If you can see it worked you answer, but I just wanted to ask something you can see there I have in DB the delete method but it doesn't delete a record from DB, do I need to write a new question or you can answer there.

Comment: @Spritzig is should delete. However, as id should be unique, no need for AND name = '?'. Issue might well be the all to common delete via a listview/spinner/recylerview and not passing the correct id (e.g. position will not equate to id nor easily be adjusted to id). Hence, you really need to add a question, could also be not refreshing the listview/recyclerview/spinner to take into consideration changed DB. As such that really needs to be another question.

Comment: you are right I have gone through Logs and it doesn't take the same id of the object.
I will post a new question thank you.

Comment: Can you see my question for ListView you have helped me each time for recyclerviews hope you will do again.
Here is the link of the question.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54478430/how-to-show-another-layout-below-the-listview

Comment: Can you see another question I have posted for RecyclerView?

Comment: @Spritzig I tend to not answer RecyclerView questions as I rarely use them as I've found that ListViews with Cursor Adapters are easier to use.

Comment: Thank you for your time and your answer you are saying that it is better to use ListView with Cursor Adapter againt RecyclerView with defined adapter ?

Comment: @Spritzig I would use ListView unless there were performance issues (never had any), the issue with RecyclerView is they don't have swapCursor (some posts on here show how to include/implement swapCursor if I recall correctly). However, some would likely burn me at the stake for suggesting not using RecyclerViews though.

Answer (score 0):

I am doing it like this try it:
1- make names `UNIQUE` in your SQLite database.

2- Add this boolean method to your database helper class:

```
public boolean checkNameExist(String p_name){
        String[] column = {"p_name"};
        db = openDatabase();
        
        String selection = "p_name=?";
        String[] selectionArgs = {p_name};
        
        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_NAME, column, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, null);
        int count = cursor.getCount();
        
        cursor.close();
        close();
        
        if(count > 0){
            return true;
            } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

3- Add this in action button listener in your activity:

```
Db_Helper myDB = new Db_Helper(AddActivity.this);
            if (!myDB.checkNameExist(name_input.getText().toString().trim())) {
          myDB.addName(  name_input.getText().toString().trim());   
            }else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Name Already exist!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
```

4- Don't forget to add:

```
.toString().trim()
```