# How to show another layout below the ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-listview

I have a db data list which extends `SQLiteOpenHelper`.
I can read the data, I can save new data but the problem it is I want below the `ListView` to show another layout which is named `clear_history` so what I am trying to do is show me `ListView` and the `TextView` below the list.
I was trying to create a `RecyclerView Adapter` but I wasn't able to achieve that.
Because I want to have a textView which I can use for click listener and do delete the db list.
Below are the photos from the list I want.
First photo is the actual design.
Second photo is what I am trying to have.

[image]
[image]

This is my code.

DatabaseHelper.class

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String TABLE_NAME = "people_table";
    private static final String COL1 = "ID";
    private static final String COL2 = "name";

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, TABLE_NAME, null, 1);
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String createTable = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                COL2 +" TEXT)";
        db.execSQL(createTable);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP IF TABLE EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);
    }
    public boolean addData(String item) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(COL2, item);
        long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);

        //if date as inserted incorrectly it will return -1
        if (result == -1) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
    public Cursor getData(){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME;
        Cursor data = db.rawQuery(query, null);
        return data;
    }

    public Cursor getItemID(String name){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        String query = "SELECT " + COL1 + " FROM " + TABLE_NAME +
                " WHERE " + COL2 + " = '" + name + "'";
        Cursor data = db.rawQuery(query, null);
        return data;
    }

    public void updateName(String newName, int id, String oldName){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        String query = "UPDATE " + TABLE_NAME + " SET " + COL2 +
                " = '" + newName + "' WHERE " + COL1 + " = '" + id + "'" +
                " AND " + COL2 + " = '" + oldName + "'";
        db.execSQL(query);
    }
    public void deleteName(int id, String name){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        String query = "DELETE FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE "
                + COL1 + " = '" + id + "'" +
                " AND " + COL2 + " = '" + name + "'";
        db.execSQL(query);
    }
}
```

FragmentHistory.XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <ListView android:id="@+id/lvHistory" android:longClickable="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent" android:soundEffectsEnabled="false"
        android:overScrollMode="never" />
    <LinearLayout android:gravity="center" android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/linLayoutEmptyList" android:paddingBottom="32.0dip" android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <ImageView android:layout_gravity="center" android:id="@+id/ivHistoryPage"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/history_query_empty"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/history_query_empty"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/history_query_empty_margin"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_history" />
        <TextView android:textSize="20.0sp" android:textColor="@color/blue_title"
            android:gravity="center" android:layout_gravity="center" android:id="@+id/tvHistoryPage"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/SVEmptyHistoryTableMessage" android:lineSpacingExtra="2.0sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

history_item.XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@drawable/selector_btn_home"
    android:id="@+id/historyLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <ImageView android:id="@id/ivHistory" style="@style/ivHistory" />
    <TextView android:id="@+id/historyName" android:layout_height="38dp" style="@style/TextViewQuery"/>
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/imgViewSetQuery" style="@style/ImageViewSetQuery" />
    <TextView android:textSize="@dimen/search_font" android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:gravity="center" android:id="@+id/btnDeleteHistory" android:background="@color/red" android:paddingLeft="5.0dip"
        android:paddingRight="5.0dip" android:visibility="gone" android:longClickable="false"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:text="@string/Delete" />
</LinearLayout>
```

FragmentHistory.class

```
public class FragmentHistory extends Fragment {
    View paramView;
    public  TextView textView, showDeleteButton, noSearch;
    public ImageView showHistoryQuery;

    DatabaseHelper mDatabaseHelper;

    private ListView mListView;
    private LinearLayout noQueries;
    ListAdapter listAdapter;
    private final Handler handler = new Handler();

    public FragmentHistory() {
    }
    private boolean switchOnOff;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        paramView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_history, container, false);
        textView = paramView.findViewById(R.id.historyName);
        noSearch = paramView.findViewById(R.id.tvHistoryPage);
        mListView = paramView.findViewById(R.id.lvHistory);
        noQueries = paramView.findViewById(R.id.linLayoutEmptyList);
        noSearch.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);
        mDatabaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(getActivity());
        doTheAutoRefresh();
        populateListView();
        ((MainActivity)getActivity()).setFragmentRefreshListener(new MainActivity.FragmentRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                ft.detach(FragmentHistory.this).attach(FragmentHistory.this).commit();
            }
        });

        return paramView;
    }


    private void doTheAutoRefresh() {
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                updateView(); // this is where you put your refresh code
                doTheAutoRefresh();
            }
        }, 1000);
    }
    private void populateListView() {


        //get the data and append to a list
        Cursor data = mDatabaseHelper.getData();
        ArrayList<String> listData = new ArrayList<>();
        while (data.moveToNext()) {
            listData.add(data.getString(1));
        }
        if (data.getCount() != 0) {
            ListAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.history_item, R.id.historyName, listData);
            mListView.setAdapter(adapter);
        } else {
            mListView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            noQueries.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } 

}
```

clear_history.XML

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/btnClearSearch"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:background="@drawable/selector_btn_home"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/history_left_padding"
    android:paddingTop="8dp"
    android:paddingBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:text="@string/SVSRClearHistoryCellTitle"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

</TextView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, you cannot see your "clear" TextView. If that is the case, just go to your XML and nest the ListView and TextView in a vertical linear layout. Then adjust how you want the two to appear.

Comment: I have tried to include the layout below the ListView but If is possible it was better to create an adapter which makes all of this and only in the Fragment to call that adapter, because you can see if the db is empty it shows me something else.

Comment: So you want the TextView to appear only when the db is not empty? You can check for this condition in your adapter as a boolean and then set its visibility accordingly.

Comment: Yes only the when db is not empty I do not have an adapter.

Comment: 1. Open https://guides.codepath.com/android/Using-an-ArrayAdapter-with-ListView for how to writet the ArrayAdapter.       2. Check for the condition in the adapter. For example, if the db returns a list, check whether it is empty with a custom boolean method. Then you can use that method in your activity when you get the list back from the db and show the TextView accordingly.

Comment: Aternatively, simply use if(list.isEmpty && list == null) {//Hide the textview}, otherwise show it

Comment: For example, with the above code. I assume that lisData is the list of strings that is returned by the db. You can check for the empty condition like this: `public void setViews() {
        if (listData.isEmpty() || listData == null) {
            //Hide the textView
        }
    }`  //Not sure if checking for null is a bit excessive but that is how I would do it. You will have to include an else statement so that you can show the TextView if the list is not empty

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lvHistory"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/linLayoutEmptyList"
        android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
        android:longClickable="true"
        android:overScrollMode="never"
        android:soundEffectsEnabled="false" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linLayoutEmptyList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="32.0dip"
        android:visibility="visible">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivHistoryPage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_fav" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvHistoryPage"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:lineSpacingExtra="2.0sp"
            android:text="SVEmptyHistoryTableMessage"
            android:textSize="20.0sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: @Spritzig in your `FragmentHistory.XML`

Comment: I have writed your xml but the problem it is that it shows me both textView, just again maybe I was not clear.
I want when the list is not empty show me the data and below the data show a `TextView` if is empty show the `LinearLayout` which is with id `linLayoutEmptyList`